# Arrays / vectors c++ pushing?

Tags: c++

I need to create a keyed array that I can push data to.

I need to store id and time, and on an event push a new id and time to the array.

After a look around, many people have suggested vectors.

I'm not sure how I would implement it though, having two keys, and how to push to them?

If anyone could help?

Comment: sounds like maybe `std::map` would be an option

Comment: Do you want to search by id and/or time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `std::vector` of `std::pair<T,U>`, where `T` and `U` are suitable data types for the id and the time.

For example:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, long> > v;
v.push_back(std::make_pair(1, 2L));
v.push_back(std::make_pair(1, 2L));
v.push_back(std::make_pair(2, 2L));
```

Comment: But how do I push new elements in?

Comment: @beans: I've added an example.

Comment: How would I access, say the 2nd pair and each element?